# what 's meanning of the marco `DK_ENTRIES` in cpython code dictobject.c

Tags: c, dictionary, macros, cpython

I read the code  of `dictobject.c` , can not figure out this

```
#define DK_ENTRIES(dk) \
    ((PyDictKeyEntry*)(&((int8_t*)((dk)->dk_indices))[DK_SIZE(dk) * DK_IXSIZE(dk)]))
```

any one can explain this macro ,hep me to read this macro and what this for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle，I find something below：

First `dk`  is `PyDictKeysObject`:

```
typedef struct _dictkeysobject PyDictKeysObject;
struct _dictkeysobject {
    Py_ssize_t dk_refcnt;
    Py_ssize_t dk_size;
    dict_lookup_func dk_lookup;
    Py_ssize_t dk_usable;
    Py_ssize_t dk_nentries;
    char dk_indices[];
};
```

note the last element`dk_indices` , ***flexible array member***

simply,

`DK_SIZE` is the `dk_size`  in struct;

`DK_IXSIZE` can be 1 or 2 or 4 or 8

`((int8_t*)((dk)->dk_indices))[DK_SIZE(dk) * DK_IXSIZE(dk)]`

is a pointer with n(dk_size*1?) offset

and the end return a pointer to `PyDictKeyEntry`

Finally, This macro return a `PyDictKeyEntry`, which have `n(dk_size*1?)` offset with `dk->dk_indices`